# page-break-before:auto not working for me....why?

Tags: css, printing

Hello my stackflow timesaving problem solving buddies,

I'm using css to style a page that is being pushed out into a PDFand contains a set of boxes ready for teams to print out.

However, some boxes are in-between pages and being cut in two.

I found the folowing...

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_print_pageba.asp

...which is not working for me on auto, the other values are not appropriate.

The page is spitting out divs whict are float:left with content inside the div

**layout:**

[div] [div] [div]

[div] [div] [div]

[div] [div] [div] < Last div is spilling onto two pages

each div had a page-break-before:auto but the divs still are splitting onto 2 pages at times.

Why is this not working for me?

can you help?

Comment: im calling the @media print at the top in style tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by applying

```
page-break-after:always;page-break-before:always;
```

However... i feel mVChr's solution would work also for other, but not in my case.

Many thanks

Comment: This will just set the break on that div to always, it will always break no matter what, which is not ideal

Answer (score 3):

To get the desired behavior you might have to add the attributes:

```
div * { page-break-before:avoid; page-break-after:avoid; }
```

in order to avoid page breaking between all of the elements inside your divs

Answer (score 3):

Try `page-break-inside:avoid`. I believe `page-break-after:avoid;` and `page-break-before:avoid` are unimplemented. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/page-break-before

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the containing `<div>` is not `inline-block`. It seems like displaying your div as `inline-block` may prevent the `page-break-auto: auto` from working.